# Send BLE raw packet through serial port

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uart, packet, smp

I was wondering if there is a way to have access through UART port to all BLE packets (all the packets that you can sniff using a sniffer and wireshark (LL, SMP, ATT, L2CAP protocols) with a BLE adapter or a nrf52 DK which is connected to a BLE device.
The output I am expecting is raw packets that can later be modified by Python or another software.
If you have any idea/sample I can work on it would be greatful.

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

My idea is to do a proxy thus I don't want to use a sniffer. I want to analyze the packets which are received/sent so I can retransmit them to another BLE adapter. Then, it will be able to connect to the first device that is far away from him (by the way it would also provides me logs of the whole traffic through python interface).

I thought to take a look at the driver I am using ("btusb") with my BLE adapter. Maybe I can program the driver to add this functionality . Do you know if it's possible ?

Here is the link of the BLE adapter I have :
https://www.amazon.fr/TP-Link-Adaptateur-Bluetooth-Portable-Ordinateur/dp/B07YLDVM6B?th=1

Comment: Could you explain more exactly what you want to achieve? Many systems have various kinds of logging support.

Comment: I've edited my first comment. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Nordic Semiconductors, the manufacturer of nRF5x series chips, has an excellent [forum](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/) for all of your questions. Try to inspect the tutorials and previous posts. You will have your answers there :)

Comment: Thanks for the link.
To be honest, I was expecting to have answers here about a solution for my BLE adapter and not the nrf device.
I just mentionned the nrf52 if there is no other solution with the BLE adapter which would lead me to continue with the nrf device.

Comment: So you basically want a GATT MITM proxy?